In imperative situation; wear or put on jewelry
I'm wondering if I want to ask some one to put on her earings, should I say:
Wear your earings.
Or
Put on your earings?

"Wear your earrings tonight - they really suit you." But if it's a request to put them on (in?) right now, you would use "Put on".

"Put on" is an action, it means a change in state from "not wearing" to "wearing".   By contrast you use "wear" to talk about the continuing action:

I put on a hat when I leave the house, and I wear my hat until I reach my office.

So if you are telling a person to "change from not wearing earing to wearing earings" you would use "put on (or put in) your earings"  The phrasal verb might be split "put your earrings on".  But if you are telling a person what to do, perhaps without changing state, use wear:  "Don't take your earrings off. Wear your earrings all evening."
